# Fine-tuning footnote style

Tags: formatting, footnotes, xparse, bigfoot, manyfoot

I need to get a grip on a custom footnote command that could be sum up by this couple of `xparse` commands:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, frenchb]{report}
    \usepackage{xparse}
    \newcounter{myfnCnt}

    % % % % % % % % MYFOOTNOTE % % % % % % % %
    % #1 footnote content
    \ProvideDocumentCommand \myfootnote{ m }
    {%  MARK
        \stepcounter{myfnCnt}\hspace{.1cm}\myfnmark%
     %  FOOTNOTE
        {\let\thefootnote\relax\footnote{\myfnmark~#1}}
    }

    % % % % % % % % MYFNMARK % % % % % % % %
    %
    \ProvideDocumentCommand \myfnmark{}
    {\texttrademark\textsuperscript{ \arabic{myfnCnt}}}

\begin{document}
They see me rollin\myfootnote{they hatin}
Son, they shook\footnote{Cause ain't no such things as halfway crooks}
\end{document}
```

The above commands do actually provide a reasonable solution meaning : the ability to tune a custom style around counters. But it's missing hyperlinks. I can do it manually but I was seeking a more elegant and robust solution, whether custom commands or "package-based". I looked into [manyfoot](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/manyfoot) and [bigfoot](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bigfoot) but I don't think they can do it or I'm missing something (probably...). For instance the `\DeclareNewFootnote[⟨footnote style⟩]{⟨suffix⟩}[⟨enumeration style⟩]` is "fixed" customization, you can't provide your own footnote style.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pschiii, actually, it can be achieved with a 2 lines solution using `manyfoot`:

```
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteB}{\texttrademark \arabic{footnoteB}}
```

Call it with : `\footnoteB{...}`

But it has troubles making hyperlinks, so here's a small modification to my custom *package-less* solution that is now fully functional (it uses your footnote's formatting):

```
% % % % % % % % MYFOOTNOTE % % % % % % % %
% #1 footnote content
\ProvideDocumentCommand \tm{ m }
{\stepcounter{myfnCnt}{\let\thefootnote\myfnmark\footnote{#1}}}

% % % % % % % % MYFNMARK % % % % % % % %
%
\ProvideDocumentCommand \myfnmark{}
{\textsc{tm} \arabic{myfnCnt}}
```

Hope this will be useful to someone.

---

**[03/15 EDIT]**

Here is a more complex cross-referenced way of doing it

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = fr_FR

\documentclass[11pt, frenchb, twoside]{report}

% IMPORTS
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcounter{__fnCnt}

% % % % % % % % FN % % % % % % % %
% #1 footnote label
% #2 footnote content
\ProvideDocumentCommand \myfn{ m m }
    {%
        \refstepcounter{__fnCnt}{\let\thefootnote\myfnLabel\footnote{#2}}
        \setcounterref{__fnCnt}{fn:#1}\label{fn:#1}
    }

% % % % % % % % FNREF % % % % % % % %
% #1 star : add as footnote
% #2 label
\ProvideDocumentCommand \myfnRef{ s m }
{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\footnote{See \myfnLink{fn:#2}.}}
    {\myfnLink{fn:#2}}%
}

% % % % % % % % FNLABEL % % % % % % % %
%
\ProvideDocumentCommand \myfnLabel{}
    {FN-\arabic{__fnCnt} }

% % % % % % % % FNLINK % % % % % % % %
% #1 label
\ProvideDocumentCommand \myfnLink{ m }
{\hyperref[#1]{\textsuperscript{FN-\getrefnumber{#1}}}, p. \getpagerefnumber{#1}}

\begin{document}
    Hello World\myfn{fnref}{This is my custom footnote} !\\[3cm]
    \blindtext[10]\myfnRef*{fnref}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was stuck with the problem of `manyfoot` not creating correct hyperlinks, until I came across this post. Your solution works nice for me (I implemented it without `xparse`, by using simply `\newcommand\tm[1]{...}` and `\newcommand\myfnmark{...}`), thanks!